# Get a unique hash of a shape independently of its rotation, mirroring or position

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

**Context**

I'm creating a labyrinth generator (actually, more like a map generator) based on "chambers" want to connect to each other. I read these from text files and then convert to an internal format composed with `LocatedNodes` which are basically a node type and x-y coordinates. I regrouped them in `NodeList` where I put all functions to rotate/mirror/normalize these nodes.
A `Map` is a aggregation of chambers so it has a single `NodeList` containing these.

To sum up the hierarchy : Map <- NodeList <- LocatedNodes

**Problem**

To connect chambers, I compare the shapes of an opening of the 1st map and the shape of the area around the opening of the 2nd map. Let's begin with a example:

```
>>> print map6.nodes # nodes of the entire map
              1 1
    0    5    0 2
   o⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
 0 |#############
   |#...........#
   |#...........#
   |#...........#
   |#............
 5 |#............
   |#........    
   |#........    
   |#........    
   |#........    
10 |#########    

>>> print map6.openings() # just the nodes placed on the opening
       1
   8   2
  o⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
4 |    .
  |.....
  |.    
  |.    
  |.    
9 |. 

>>> print map7.nodes # map we want to connect with the other
             1   1
   0    5    0   4
  o⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
0 |    ###########
  |    ..........#
  |    ..........#
  |..............#
  |..............#
5 |..............#
  |..............#
7 |###############

>>> print map7.joinable_on() # area around the map7.openings()
   -
   1   3
  o⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
1 |    .
  |.....
  |.    
  |.    
  |.    
6 |. 

>>> map7.joinable_on().normalized(x=0,y=0) == map6.openings().normalized(x=0, y=0)
True
```

It is not hard to compare map6.openings() et map7.joinable_on() because when the positions of the nodes are normalized, I can do a one-to-one comparison.

**BUT**, the hard part comes now:
I want to be able to compare these shapes independently of their position, rotation or mirroring.

**What I tried**

When searching for ideas, I found the [pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) (this function links two int to a unique int, so each coordinate x-y becomes a unique int). With that I could identify a shape uniquely by applying recursively this function on (x,y) coordinates. First problem, the unique int is really unique, so even with a 90° rotation the int changes, so I can't compare two shapes this way.

**Question**

Do you have an idea or a solution to help me get a unique id of a shape that doesn't change when this shape get mirrored, translated or rotated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general scheme for creating ids that don't change when a shape is mirrored, translated, or rotated. Start with an id that does care about mirroring, translating, and rotating. When you get a shape, consider every possible mirroring, rotation, and translation, and compute an id for each case. This gives you a large number of ids, so just pick the numerically smallest one.

For the case of translation, another idea might be more practical - before (and/or after) doing all this, translate the shape so that its centre of gravity is at the origin, or as near to the origin as you can make it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should have your list of shapes with no translation, rotation, or mirroring. Then, to create a map you index a shape and provide a transformation matrix. So your input file would look something like:

```
Shapes
    shape1
    shape2
    shape3
    etc.
```

Those shapes all are built at the origin and have no translation.

Then, your map becomes:

```
Map
    0 (index to shape1), transformation matrix (scaling, rotation, translation, mirroring)
    2 (index to shape3), transformation matrix
    0 (index to shape1), different transformation matrix
```

Then all you have to do to determine if two shapes in the map are the same is compare their indexes.